# GDB 7.9.1 compilation fails

Tags: build, makefile, gdb

I need the newest GDB to install arm-none-eabi-gdb from macports, but I get this compliling GDB from sources, what's wrong?

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7fhq_OsB_AsU3dPUUlJanJkUjg/view?usp=sharing) is build log

Comment: make[8]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all-target'.

Comment: That's not an error, it just means that everything is made already. Why would you need to compile this anyway if you're using `MacPorts`, since usually it does all the compiling, installing, etc.

Comment: MacPorts doesnt have the newest gdb.

Comment: Cannot replicate. `git clone git://sourceware.org/git/binutils-gdb.git` `git checkout tags/gdb-7.9.1-release`, compiled without a hitch on OS X 10.3.3.